# Covered Queries do not work with partial indices

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

**Update**: I created a ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-48777

Please see the example below. Why does 2nd query perform document lookups?

```js
db.createCollection('inventory')
db.getCollection('inventory').insertMany([

    { type: 'food', color: 'yellow', name: 'banana' },
    { type: 'food', color: 'red',    name: 'cherry' },
    { type: 'car',  color: 'yellow', name: 'taxi' }

])

db.getCollection('inventory').createIndex({ type: 1, name: 1 }, { name: 'byType' })
db.getCollection('inventory').createIndex({ name: 1 },          { name: 'onlyRed', partialFilterExpression: {  color: 'red' } })

// find cherry by type -> totalDocsExamined = 0 (as expected)
db.getCollection('inventory').find({ type: 'food', name: /c/ }, { name: 1, _id: 0 }).explain('executionStats').executionStats.totalDocsExamined

// find cherry by color -> totalDocsExamined = 1 :-(
db.getCollection('inventory').find({ color: 'red', name: /c/ }, { name: 1, _id: 0 }).explain('executionStats').executionStats.totalDocsExamined
```

The indices of the example above are:

```js
db.getCollection('inventory').getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "type" : 1.0,
            "name" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "byType"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "name" : 1.0
        },
        "name" : "onlyRed",
        "partialFilterExpression" : {
            "color" : "red"
        }
    }
]
```

All the following version show this behaviour: 4.2.1, 4.2.7, 4.4.0-rc9

I can't find anything in the documentation for [Covered Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) and [Partial Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) why it shouldn't be supported.

explain of query1:

```js
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "demo.inventory",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "type" : {
                        "$eq" : "food"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : {
                        "$regex" : "c"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
            "transformBy" : {
                "name" : 1.0,
                "_id" : 0.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "name" : {
                        "$regex" : "c"
                    }
                },
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "type" : 1.0,
                    "name" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "byType",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "type" : [],
                    "name" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "type" : [ 
                        "[\"food\", \"food\"]"
                    ],
                    "name" : [ 
                        "[\"\", {})", 
                        "[/c/, /c/]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_COVERED",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 3,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "transformBy" : {
                "name" : 1.0,
                "_id" : 0.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "filter" : {
                    "name" : {
                        "$regex" : "c"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 3,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "type" : 1.0,
                    "name" : 1.0
                },
                "indexName" : "byType",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "type" : [],
                    "name" : []
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "type" : [ 
                        "[\"food\", \"food\"]"
                    ],
                    "name" : [ 
                        "[\"\", {})", 
                        "[/c/, /c/]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 2,
                "seeks" : 1,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongo",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.0-rc9",
        "gitVersion" : "bea79f76addfe4b754c8696db029c5b3c762041c"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591984674, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591984674, 1)
}
```

explain of query2 (using partial index):

```js
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "demo.inventory",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "color" : {
                        "$eq" : "red"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : {
                        "$regex" : "c"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
            "transformBy" : {
                "name" : 1.0,
                "_id" : 0.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "color" : {
                        "$eq" : "red"
                    }
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                        "name" : {
                            "$regex" : "c"
                        }
                    },
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "name" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "onlyRed",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "name" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : true,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "name" : [ 
                            "[\"\", {})", 
                            "[/c/, /c/]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "PROJECTION_SIMPLE",
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 2,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 0,
            "restoreState" : 0,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "transformBy" : {
                "name" : 1.0,
                "_id" : 0.0
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "color" : {
                        "$eq" : "red"
                    }
                },
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 2,
                "advanced" : 1,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 0,
                "restoreState" : 0,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "docsExamined" : 1,
                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                        "name" : {
                            "$regex" : "c"
                        }
                    },
                    "nReturned" : 1,
                    "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                    "works" : 2,
                    "advanced" : 1,
                    "needTime" : 0,
                    "needYield" : 0,
                    "saveState" : 0,
                    "restoreState" : 0,
                    "isEOF" : 1,
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "name" : 1.0
                    },
                    "indexName" : "onlyRed",
                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                    "multiKeyPaths" : {
                        "name" : []
                    },
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : true,
                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "name" : [ 
                            "[\"\", {})", 
                            "[/c/, /c/]"
                        ]
                    },
                    "keysExamined" : 1,
                    "seeks" : 1,
                    "dupsTested" : 0,
                    "dupsDropped" : 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "mongo",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "4.4.0-rc9",
        "gitVersion" : "bea79f76addfe4b754c8696db029c5b3c762041c"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1591984064, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : { "$binary" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=", "$type" : "00" },
            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1591984064, 1)
}
```

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with indexing in Mongo, but I can tell you that in general any database may chose to not use an index if doing so would not help performance.  This is true for relational SQL, at least.

Comment: Is this index creation statement correct? `db.getCollection('inventory').createIndex({ name: 1 }, { name: 'onlyRed' }, { partialFilterExpression: {  color: 'red' } })`. Would it be worth checking your indices to make sure you're creating the ones that you intended?

Comment: @willis There was indeed a typo in my example. Sorry for that. I corrected it. The indices of my real collection are different. I tried to find a minimal example here.

Comment: What are full query plans for both queries?

Comment: @D.SM I added them.

Comment: It seems that the index *is* used and then the server performs a filter stage which shouldn't be needed. I would report this to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While as you know there is a limitation in these types of indexes tracked in MongoDB Jira, there is a simple workaround to this - add the field in the partial index expression to the index definition as a key. This will allow index only plan to be chosen.

That was tracked by [SERVER-28889](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28889) which was recently fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's a know bug, which is already tracked here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-26580

The creation date of the issue is Oct 11 2016. :-(