# Slow queries with partial indices

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I am using MongoDB 6.0. I have a collection with millions of documents. I have to run certain queries on this collection.

I have created indices that support fast query and counting.

The problem is that I also have a low cardinality field (`visible` of type boolean), which I also have to support for querying, but only with `visible: true` (I never have to run a query with `visible: false`).

My idea was to create the same indices that I use without the `visible` field, and for this I used [partial indices](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-partial/) with same keys and a filter expression:

```
{partialFilterExpression: {"visible": true}}
```

Note that `"visible"` is not added to the index keys, it's just part of the `partialFilterExpression`.

My thoughts were that the same queries with `"visible": true` would have no performance penalty, if anything, they should run faster as they (should) use an index that has less entries (only documents where `visible=true`).

But these queries (especially the counting) turn out to be much slower.

I used `explain()` to see if the proper indices are used, and often they weren't. So I used `hint` to ensure they are, which `explain()` also confirmed, but the queries are still much slower.

What could be the cause? How can I ensure that queries and counting with `visible: true` run as fast as queries without the `visible` filter?

Comment: Please show us the full index specification, the query and 1-2 sample documents. I am a bit surprised that a user with 300k+ reputations is asking a question lacking such relevant information.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didn't include the index definition(s) because they match exactly except the `partialFilterExpression` part, and the query without the `visible` filter runs fast, and the one with `visible` filter doesn't. Anyway, as can be read in the accepted answer, this is a bug in MongoDB itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a current limitation of the database, a missing optimization at its core. This question is effectively a duplicate of [Covered Queries do not work with partial indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62342543/covered-queries-do-not-work-with-partial-indices). If you follow the links, you end up at [ticket SERVER-28889](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28889) tracking the request.

It looks like this improvement will be available in an upcoming version of MongoDB. In the meantime the workaround would be to also add the field as a key to the index (along with it being in the partial filter expression).

Comment: This seems to be the issue and solution, thanks.